# How to get logged user id in REST API

Tags: java, rest, authentication, spring-security

I have built a Java application with the REST API convention. I working on endpoint which returns objects only if object is connected with user by common id in database(ManyToOne annotation). In order to achieve that i need current logged user id for comapring it with object's user id. If Ids are the same, endpoint returns data. I know solutions as "Principal" or "Authentication" classes but they provide everything except of "id". I used spring security http basic for authentication.
My authentication classes:

```
@Component
public class CustomAuthenticator implements AuthenticationProvider {

    private final UserRepository userRepository;

    private final PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

    @Autowired
    public CustomAuthenticator(UserRepository userRepository, @Lazy PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder) {
        this.userRepository = userRepository;
        this.passwordEncoder = passwordEncoder;
    }

    @Override
    public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication) throws AuthenticationException {

        String login = authentication.getName();
        String password = authentication.getCredentials().toString();

        User user = userRepository.findByLogin(login).orElseThrow(() -> new EntityNotFoundException("User not found"));
        if (!passwordEncoder.matches(password, user.getPassword())) {
            throw new BadCredentialsException("Bad credentials");
        }

        return new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(login, password, convertAuthorities(user.getRoles()));

    }

    private Set<GrantedAuthority> convertAuthorities(Set<UserRole> userRoles) {
        Set<GrantedAuthority> authorities = new HashSet<>();
        for (UserRole ur : userRoles) {
            authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(ur.getRole().toString()));
        }
        return authorities;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean supports(Class<?> authentication) {
        return authentication.equals(UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken.class);
    }
}
```

SECURITY CONFIG CLASS:

```
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
@EnableWebSecurity
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    private final CustomAuthenticator customAuthenticator;

    public SecurityConfig(CustomAuthenticator customAuthenticator) {
        this.customAuthenticator = customAuthenticator;
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder = PasswordEncoderFactories.createDelegatingPasswordEncoder();
        return passwordEncoder;
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/api").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/api/register").permitAll()
                //TODO everybody now has access to database, change it later
                .antMatchers("/h2-console/**").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .httpBasic();

        http
                .csrf().disable()
                .headers().frameOptions().disable();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.authenticationProvider(customAuthenticator);
    }
}
```

Does someone know how to resolve that problem ?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `UserDetails` class and set id for the `username` field, this class provides by spring security.

If you don't want that solution, you can create a `Subclass extend UserDetails` class and decide an id field. When receiving the request, parse principal to `UserDetails` or `subclass extends UserDetails` to get the id

Ex:

```
Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
UserDetails userPrincipal = (UserDetails)authentication.getPrincipal();
```

Comment: that is perfect answer.

Comment: I added some pieces of code from my project, are you still sure that yuor solution fit to my autentiaction method ?

Comment: if you used the spring security, you can manage `user profile` in `UserDetails` class.
prefer: https://www.baeldung.com/get-user-in-spring-security